# Exchange Web Services - Office 365 in Vbscript

Tags: c#, vbscript, exchangewebservices

I need to do a project where the User will insert in one Form  his Office 365 email and password. I need with Exchange Web Services API and users credentials to retrieve his Contacts and search for a specific Number. 
So far on the tutorials most of the code which is provided is in c#. But i need to do that in vbscript. I am trying to use .NET dlls that are provided for C# to CreateObject for the ExchangeService.
In c# this is how it creates a new ExhchangeService :

```
      ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    service.Timeout = 1000 * timeoutSeconds;
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password);
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(userName, redirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

How can i include the .NET dll file and use it to create new Object?
There is another way to authenticate with users credentials and retrieve Contacts ?

Answer (score 1):

First question is why do you need to use VBS ? why this constraint ? can you JavaScript instead

You won't be able to use the EWS Managed API .net assembly in VBS as it has no Com interfaces. If you absolutely must use VBS then create a console application in C# compile it as an EXE and then execute the EXE from your VBS code. Otherwise if you can use Powershell instead of VBS then you can will be able to fully access the EWS Managed API objects.

If you can use Javascript then look at the REST Api for Office365 instead https://dev.outlook.com/

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Hello Glen , Thank you for your Response. I actually need for sure to use Vbscript for a  project i have to do. Is not necessary for me to use EWS Managed API , i can use  REST API for Office365.